# Problemas com arquivo PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, pdf

Estou mostrando um arquivo PDF diretamente no navegador. No Google Chrome, funciona perfeitamente, porém, se utilizar o FireFox, o PDF fica conforme a imagem abaixo.

Será que tinha que colocar alguma config a mais para o Firefox?
O arquivo PDF está ok, se abrir diretamente na pasta.

#### Código da Controller

```
public ActionResult Boleto(string id)
{
    var arquivoPDF = Path.Combine(MegaBoleto.PastaPDF(), String.Format("{0}.{1}", id, "pdf"));
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(arquivoPDF))
    {
        return File(arquivoPDF, "application/pdf");
    }
    return View();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nesse trecho não há problema nenhum. Não é a fonte que está sendo utilizada no PDF, tentou troca-lá? Informe como ele é gerado.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann o PDF é gerado pelo AcBR Boleto, em Fortes Report e a exportação é a padrão dele.

Comment: O Firefox usa [seu próprio plugin para visualização de PDF](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox) assim como outros navegadores. Por isso o problema ocorre só nele, [troque por outro](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-built-pdf-viewer-and-use-another-viewer) pra ver se funciona, mas a correção ideal seria testar outras fontes, mas não conheço o AcBR Boleto.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann está sendo utilizado a fonte Arial

Comment: Você conhece essa biblioteca que está usando pra gerar o boleto? É possível trocar a fonte que é usada pra testar? Você pode postar o trecho que gera o boleto ou um exemplo parecido?